# Display Inline-Block Overflow

Tags: css

I have two objects within a parent. The two objects are each given a set width of 60%. I want them to sit side-by-side within the parent and cause overflow. To attempt this, I used the following

```
.item{display: inline-block;}
```

However, all they did was stack on top of each other.

I tried to illustrate below

What I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81UqM.jpg

What happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qji5.jpg

Comment: Something to do with `white-space: nowrap` on the parent I think.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you! How do I give you credit?

Comment: I don't think my vague  and uncertain comment needs any credit :-)

Comment: Yes you do! It helped me and that's what I came here for. Now get some credit darnit!

Comment: Hi Borif. You are welcome to delete [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760787/pdo-counting-amount-of-like-matches) as you wish, given that Stack Overflow offers that option. Nevertheless, bear in mind for people who are in the middle of commenting to assist you, finding that a question has been deleted is rather frustrating. Where you are asked for code/attempt/examples, please provide them in future. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer You really commented here? I was getting frustrated with my question so I deleted it.

Comment: Well, that was evident. But there was no need for you to get frustrated: we needed more detail about your problem, and some of us are experienced enough to know it is not wise to assist without a good idea of the problem at hand. Much time can be wasted on the wrong path otherwise. It is very usual to be asked for clarifications on this site, and deletion is rarely the most suitable response - not least because you still have the problem.

Comment: @halfer I'm working on a solution right now, so it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `white-space: nowrap` to the parent should do what you're trying to achieve.

```css
.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```